# Diference between 2 TextBox user Form

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I am new here..and I need a help pls

Hello guys

I am developing a form in VBA that has "Text 1" and "Text 2" which are trying to subtract between them and show the result in Text3. I am currently using a macro below which is working.

My problem is that when I'm trying to create a validation, in which, for example, if the user types "Text 1" = 1000 and "Text 2" = 2000, I would like the vba to display a message to the user such as "Text1" cannot be less than "Text2".and a reset Text1 and Text 2 and Text3.
Could you please help me?

```
Sub SubtrairTXT()
'
On Error Resume Next

If Text1.Value <> "" And Text2.Value <> "" Then
    If Text1.Value >= 0 And Text2.Value >= 0 Then
        Text3.Value = Text1.Value - Text2.Value
        Text3.Value = Format(Text3.Value, "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00")
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur. If you don't see the errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them the code cannot work. • Remove it and fix your errors. • [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)